# Multiple Conditions for Swift 'If' Statement?

Tags: if-statement, swift

Is there a way to write an If statement is Swift such as the following?

```
if a>b or c/d {
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to downvote this question. Everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: Agreed with Stew. Also, you can do complex multiple conditions by using brackets to indicate order of operations as such:

if (a==b && b==c) || (a==0 && c==1)

Comment: some one know if i can.. this `if number == (1, 2, 3)` or maybe ranges of numbers ? `if number == 1..3`

Comment: @marlonpya no, you can't

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just like everywhere:

```
if a > b || d % c == 0 {
   // do sth
}
```

I assume your `c/d` means you'd like `d` to be a multiple of `c`.

Comment: Sorry that was meant to be c>d or something of the like. Thanks so much though! That was quick and easy haha

Answer (score 12):

Swift uses the same operators as all C-based languages, so

```
if a > b || c < d {
}
```

where `||` is the OR operator, `&&` is the AND operator.

The list of all operators can be found in [Swift Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_108)

Not sure what `c/d` condition is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 3):

for and operation we can use

> if x==y && y == z {    //perform some operations }

for or operation we can use

> if x==y || y == z {    //perform some operations }