# How to write if condition with OR operator in swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have following code in objective-c:-

```
- if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
   valueForKey:@"habibi_Gender"] || ![[NSUserDefaults
   standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"my_Gender"])  {   // do something
   here }
```

I want to write this same condition in swift.

Comment: let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let habibi = defaults.stringForKey("habibi_Gender")
let mygender =  defaults.stringForKey("my_Gender")

if !(habibi != nil  || mygender != nil)
{
    // do something here
    
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
    let habibi = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().defaults.stringForKey("habibi_Gender")
    let mygender = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults(). defaults.stringForKey("my_Gender")

    if !(habibi != nil  || mygender != nil)
    {
        // do something here

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i am not sure why spacing is so much issue in swift, if i do not give space between habibi and != , it starts throwing error. But anyways that's a different story, thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same

```
if condition1 || condition2 {
    //do something
}
```

Question was asked already here: [Multiple Conditions for Swift 'If' Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463150/multiple-conditions-for-swift-if-statement)